# Perl regular expressions explanation

Tags: regex, perl, match

I was hoping to get a little explanation I have the following script:

```
open (FILE, '2.txt');
@DNA = <FILE>;
$DNA = join ('', @DNA);

print "DNA = ". $DNA . "\n";

$a=0;
while ($DNA =~ //ig) {$a++;}
print "Total characters = ".$a."\n";

$b=0;
while ($DNA =~ /fl/ig) {$b++;}
print "Total fl = ".$b."\n";

$c=0;
while ($DNA =~ /[^fl]/ig) {$c++;}
print "Total character less fl = ".$c."\n";

exit;
```

The text document "2.txt" contains the following characters:

```
flkkkklllkkfewnofnewofewfl
```

When I run the script I get the following outputs:

```
DNA = flkkkklllkkfewnofnewofewfl
Total characters = 27
Total fl = 2
Total character less fl = 16
```

My question is, why when I do
`while ($DNA =~ /fl/ig) {$b++;}` if counts all the instances of fl together,

but when I do
`while ($DNA =~ /[^fl]/ig) {$c++;}` it counts the number of characters that
are neither an f or and l (i.e. the f & the l are treated separately).

I was looking for the script to count the number of characters that are not fl (i.e. treated together)

Answer (score 2):

`[fl]` is a character class, means *f* or *l*.
It doesn't mean the substring `fl`.

So `[^fl]` counts all the characters that are not f or l.

However, you could do that with a regex like this -

`/[^fl]|f(?!l)|(?<!f)l/`

Formatted:

```
    [^fl]          # Not f nor l
 |  f (?! l )      # f not followed by l
 |  (?<! f ) l     # l not following f
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Another quick question, why does it work when I count the number of instances of "fl" by while ($DNA =~ /fl/ig) {$b++;}

Comment: It just matches all the `fl` substrings.

Answer (score 0):

Keeping it simple, maybe consider dropping all the instances of "fl" first, then simply counting the remaining characters:

```
$DNA =~ s/fl//g;
print "Total characters less fl = ".length($DNA)."\n";
```